# Is it possible to use autoresizingMask to keep the percentage ratio

Tags: ios, autoresizingmask

I have a view with 1 tableView which is allocated 50% of screen height and 100% of screen width.

I have following code:

```
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    //tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

However, when I rotate the screen/device, height does not adjust to 50% of new orientation. width does adjust to 100%

How can I get height adjusted as well, if its possible?

Comment: You definitely need `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` if you want the height to change. Any reason you can't use AutoLayout in this project?

Comment: My understanding of AutoLayout is same as autoresizingMask. I am sure it will have its own set of issues. Since I know autoresizingMask little more, I was hoping to use it.

Comment: It wont work really. Autoresizing mask is not powerful enough. Use autoresizing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to setup frames; `tableView`'s superview frame must not be empty:

```
tableView.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Then, setup `tableView` frame and masks:

```
CGRect frame = tableView.superview.frame;
frame.size.width /= 2;
tableView.frame = frame;

tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```